# Trouble Configuring Webpack

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I am having trouble configuring webpack for a react project and it has been frustrating me for some time now. Here is my code so far:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                    plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';
ReactDom.render(
    <App/>,

    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

and index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've run the following commands to install webpack and babel dependencies. Here are the commands I've followed: 
`yarn add --save-dev webpack@^3.2.0 webpack-dev-server@^2.5.1` , `yarn add --save-dev babel-cli babel-core babel-loader babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react` , and `yarn add --save react react-dom` . After running `yarn start` from the project's root directory, the console output says:

```
yarn run v1.15.2
warning ../package.json: No license field
$ webpack-dev-server
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack:
- /Users/mg185312/Documents/MyProjects/project/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js
- /Users/mg185312/Documents/MyProjects/project/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mg185312/Documents/MyProjects/project/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:22:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:777:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/mg185312/Documents/MyProjects/project/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js',
    '/Users/mg185312/Documents/MyProjects/project/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Am I using the wrong version of webpack or any of the babel dependencies? I am also wondering why I don't see `"webpack": "^3.2.0"` or `babel-cli` listed in my dependencies, or why they are in `"dependencies"` instead of `"devDependencies"` even though I've used the flag `--save-dev` in all of my commands. Is there something wrong? Did I mess something up when I did the very first thing with `yarn init` ? Should I be using npm instead of yarn? (I use yarn because honestly I despise npm and would rather not be bothered using it). I would also like to add that I could just use `npx create-react-app project` , but I would rather not use a boilerplate at this point, as I would like to be able to have more control over my project. Any help would be appreciated as I've been banging my head against a wall over this for some time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output did you see from your attempt to install webpack? Did you run it in the right directory?

Comment: Yes, I was running `yarn add webpack` from the project's root directory. I was actually able to resolve my webpack configuration issue by using the `--dev` flag instead of the `--save-dev` flag (I am new to some of this, and I learned that `--dev` is for yarn, whereas `--save-dev` is for npm). Additionally, all babel modules are written in a different format. For example, `babel-core` is now `@babel/core`. I actually have a working configuration that I'm considering sharing, though I don't know how much that would help anyone, especially since version compatibilities change so frequently.

Comment: It depends which version of babel you're using. And didn't yarn say anything when you used an unrecognised flag? The default behaviour is to add it as a non-dev dependency, which would also add it to your package file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `webpack` is not correctly installed in your dependencies.

Retry this:

```
yarn add -D webpack
```

Note: with Yarn, you need to use `-D` or `--dev` (rather than `--save-dev`) to install dev dependencies.